# Find ∂x/∂u if I know ∂u/∂x?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, jacobian

I have the following transformation

$\it{u=x^2-y^2}$

$\it{v=2xy}$

I want to calculate $\frac{∂x}{∂u}$ $(0,2)$ and I know that the transformation is bijective around the point $(1,1)$. The answer is $\frac{1}{4}$, but I am unsure how to tackle this problem. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: In this context, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the rate of change of $u$ with respect to $x$ *as $y$ is held constant*, whereas $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ is the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $u$ *as $v$ is held constant*, which is why they aren't just inverses of each other.

Comment: Therefore (as an alternative to the Jacobian approach) you could differentiate both equations with respect to $x$, set $v'=0$ to find $y'$, and plug this into the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the Jacobian of the map $(x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ at $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ is the entry $1,1$ of the inverse of that Jacobian.

The Jacobian is

$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
\partial{u}/\partial{x} & \partial{u}/\partial{y} \\
\partial{v}/{\partial{x}} & \partial{v}/\partial{y}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2& -2 \\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and its inverse
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1/4& 1/4 \\
-1/4& 1/4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Leading  to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Write $J$ for the Jacobian matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{
\partial{u}/\partial{x} & \partial{u}/\partial{y} \\
\partial{v}/{\partial{x}} & \partial{v}/\partial{y}
}.
$$
You want to find the upper left entry of the inverse matrix to $J$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have  the jacobian which is \begin{pmatrix}
2x & -2y \\
2y & 2x 
\end{pmatrix} When I find the inverse I get that the upper left entry is $\frac{2x}{4x^2+4y^2}$ which is 0 in the point (0,2). But the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Pi314 You need to compute the Jacobian at $(1,1)$ not $(0,2)$. $(0,2)$ is the image under the map of $(1,1)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am not quite sure I understand, I want to find the value of the partial derivative at (0,2)? Why can I not just find the general term for the inverse and the plug in (0,2)?

Comment: In fact as you take the inverse map you need to take the value at the inverse image, which is $(1,1)$.

Comment: I see, thank you! So for any point (a,b) I would need to calculate the inverse Jacobian at the "inverse" value